# JQuery pass function name to a variable and calling it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am tweaking my pagination, but because the pagination is only doing GET request, I am planning to make it to do AJAX Post request, doing this because there can be a several pagination in a single page.

```
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $(document).on('click', '.pagination a', function(e)
        {
            e.preventDefault();

            var page = $(this).attr('href').split('page')[1];
            var function_name = $(this).parent().closest('div').attr('data-function-name');
    });
```

I am planning to call an existing function by using the function_name then add the page as a parameter pass by value for that function

lets say

```
function fetch_records(page)
{
    //do something here
}


function fetch_notes(page)
{
    //do something here
}
```

Anyone can show me how this is done without using EVAL? Thanks.

## UPDATE

```
            <div id="div_paginate" class="col-sm-6" style="display:block;" data-function-name="fetch_records">
                <div id="div_possible_duplicate_paginate" class="pull-right"></div>
            </div>
```

What I am thinking to do is that, for every pagination div, I will have that data attribute where it will contain the function name it should call.

Comment: Inside the click handler you just pass the argument, as in `fetch_records(page);`

Comment: I do not want to tweak the pagination created by server code, because everytime I run composer update, all tweaking I made is lost.  So I was thinking to do this way instead.

Comment: What's the value of data-function-name? Are those defined server side as well?

Comment: I have updated the question to answer your question.

Comment: With onclick="fetch_records('page1')" it would be so much simpler :-)

Comment: @jyrkim I do not really want to tweak the pagination which generates the pagination. rather I just want to add something for it to work the way I want it to

Comment: @Ponce okay, no problem :-)

Comment: I just discovered this useful link http://www.sitepoint.com/call-javascript-function-string-without-using-eval/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make a module that would contain all the AJAX methods and call particular methods from this container based on your `data-function-name`. Something like this:

Test HTML:

```
<div id="div_paginate" data-function-name="fetch_records" class="grid">
    Records..
</div>

<div id="div_paginate" data-function-name="fetch_notes" class="grid">
    Notes..
</div>
```

JS:

```
// Module that contains your particular methods
var FuncsModule = (function(){
    var fetch_records = function(page)
    {
        alert('fetching records ' + page + '..');
    }
    var fetch_notes = function(page)
    {
        alert('fetching notes ' + page + '..');
    }
    return {
        fetch_records: fetch_records,
        fetch_notes: fetch_notes
    }
})();

// Implementation
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '.grid', function(e){                                 
        var action = ($(this).attr('data-function-name')),
            page = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1); // some random number for tests
        if (typeof(action) !== 'undefined'){
            FuncsModule[action].call(this, page);
        }
    });
});
```

jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/avup23cg/

Comment: I am still trying to figure how I can add this code to my code. I am getting this error: TypeError: funcModule[fetchRecord] is undefined
 

funcModule[fetchRecord].call(this, page);

Comment: @Ponce would you please have a jsfiddle so I could have a look on exact code?

Comment: @Ponce Got it :) You had only minor bugs (`<script>` tag is not allowed within jsfiddle JS code; then you also mistyped some words, such as `fetch_records` instead of `fetchRecord`; most importantly, our `funcModule` should not be within `$(document).ready` since it's module. It doesn't have to wait for DOM. Please, check updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ntyu7ha9/3/  and note that a few bugs still rises but I believe those are related to your internal variables such as `get_input_data_contact_email` which are not included in the jsfiddle. Hope it helps

Comment: I see. Thank you. Sorry about that. It is my first time using it.